# Bundler install takes a longer time to execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Fetching gem metadata and full source index takes an inordinate time. I am using the latest bundler.

1. Is there a way to share this information across multiple users in a laptop or across an entire LAN.
2. What mechanisms are available to make this run faster.

   bundle install
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.

   Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API

   Fetching full source index from https://rubygems.org/

   Using rake (10.0.3)

   Using abstract (1.0.0)

   Installing i18n (0.6.1)

   Installing multi_json (1.7.2)

   Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: too many connection resets (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/gems/activesupport-3.2.13.gem)

   An error occurred while installing activesupport (3.2.13), and Bundler cannot continue.

   Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '3.2.13'` succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing your gemfile to use http://rubygems.org instead of https for some reason speeds things up drastically